# How to have classic ASP form recognize change in input

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

So my ordeal is that I want for the the submit button to be disabled when there is no input and to not be disabled when there is input. However, the button remains disabled no matter the condition. Is there a way around this or am I trying to achieve the impossible. I want the button to change instantaneously, as soon as the second input is put in.

Here's the code:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputName">First Number</label>
        <input type="num" class="form-control" id="num1" name="num1" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputUsername">Second Number</label>
        <input type="num" class="form-control" id="num2" name="num2" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputUsername">Answer:</label>
        <% 
        numm1 = request.Form("num1")
        numm2 = request.Form("num2")
        answer = numm1 * numm2
        response.write(answer) 
        %>
        </div>
            <%  If ((numm1="")And(numm2="")) Then %>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" disabled >Submit</button>
            <%  End If %>
            <%  If ((numm1<>"")And(numm2<>"")) Then %>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" >Submit</button>
            <%  End If %>
    </form>
```

Any suggestions? I'm relatively decent with PHP and I'm giving classic ASP a go just to broaden my scope...

Comment: Just like php, asp/vbscript is executed server-side. If you want things to happen client-side, you'll need to add JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do must be done on the Client side (JavaScript), not Server-side (ASP-Classic).

You'll need to create a JavaScript function to execute with onKeyUp() events on both fields. The function should check the values of the two fields and disable the button based on your criteria.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, considering all that JavaScript, why not evaluate the problem and display answer in JavaScript while you're at it?